# Rewrite rule "URL as parameter" in IIS web.config (returns error 500)

Tags: azure, mod-rewrite, iis, web-config

I mange "URL as parameter" with Apache .htaccess using flag `[B]`

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(\S+)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?i=%1 [B,L]
```

Unfortunately can't figure out how to do the same in IIS web.config

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>      
            <clear/>              
            <add value="index.php"/>
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      <rewrite>
          <rules>
                <rule name="rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?i={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Lets say web.config is under http://localhost/dir/web.config ...

**Results:** Opening http://localhost/dir/ and http://localhost/dir/example executes index.php correctly, but accessing **http://localhost/dir/i/http://example.org returns error 500** `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

**Expected:** http://localhost/dir/i/http://example.org must execute index.php with `$_GET['i']` value `dir/i/http://example.org`

It seems IIS doesn't allow to use in URL `:/`... Any workaround/fix for it?

Tools like http://www.htaccesstowebconfig.com doesn't convert .htaccess correctly, your help/advice would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I find the way to respond URLs containing `:/` and returning multiple slash value/query `://...` (example URL http://localhost/dir/i/http://example.org) was by using `UNENCODED_URL`; fallowing **answer:**

```
<rule name="Index" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?i={UNENCODED_URL}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Notice, it will return value begining `/` like `/dir/i/http://example.org`.

Any hacking around to allow special symbols, like

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" AllowRestrictedChars="1" UrlSegmentMaxLength="2048" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
<security>
    <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="false" />
</security>
```

didn't give any benefit in order to solve the issue (no need for it).

**Update:** It works fine on local Windows 10 machine, but still returns error 500 on Azure servers. No idea why.

```
ModuleName  IIS Web Core
Notification    BEGIN_REQUEST
HttpStatus  500
HttpReason  Internal Server Error
HttpSubStatus   19
ErrorCode   The specified path is invalid.
 (0x800700a1)
ConfigExceptionInfo \\?\D:\home\site\wwwroot\i\http:\web.config ( 0) :Cannot read configuration file
```